# h:link and parameters JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a problem with passing parameters with h:link

```
<h:link id="partyname" outcome="memberlist" value="memberlist">
    <f:param  name="partyname" value="#{partyBean.currentparty.name}" /> 
</h:link>
```

but when i click on the link the url generated is simply the follow:

```
http://localhost:8080/DigitalStateSWProjectWeb/memberlist.xhtml;jsessionid=29a181ab1a3170496ca9b0200f52
```

The main problem is also that i am sure that

```
#{partyBean.currentparty.name}
```

is a correct code and it is generating the correct string..
I'd like that my generated URL is somethink like:

```
http://localhost:8080/DigitalStateSWProjectWeb/memberlist.xhtml?partyname=Yellow
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `metadata` between `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` tags. It will solve your problem.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="partyname" value="#{partyBean.currentparty.name}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

And add `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core` to the `<ui:fragment>` for recognition `metadata`

```
<ui:fragment xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Comment: Sorry, just another small question... if I have now my h:link in each row of a given dataTable, and so my param is changing for each row, how can i set my f:metatada ?!?!? I have to know the "itaration" object on the table...

Comment: take a look a this topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for , here is a clear explanation